# Creating points from a one to many relationship

Tags: qgis, geometry, relates

I have created a one to many relationship within a geometric shapefile. Is it possible to to create points from the 'many' records in this shapefile as I would like to output the records into a leaflet based map for other users? I'm using qgis 2.18. [image]

Comment: I do not know whether QGIS has such a functionality or not. If you already have a referencing field in your child layer ('many'), `Split vector layer` tool using the referencing field as the unique id may give you what you need.

Comment: No, that operation does not work. It produces a single record new layer where none of the Related data is used.

Comment: What geometry has your parent layer got? (polygon, line, point)

Comment: My parent is a polygon layer.